# clang finding operation ASAP times

Tags: clang

I need to read the DFG of a program and find the ASAP scheduling values of operations in clang. I've written the preprocessor that parses the main file and builds the AST.

From here however, I have no idea how to proceed. Are there any built-in classes that I can use? If so how do I use them to get the ASAP values? If not what do I have to do to get them manually?